# Labels as features in anomaly detection

Tags: class-imbalance, multiclass-classification, anomaly-detection

I have a dataset born to solve a classification problem. Due to the imbalances of the Y, i choose to move to an anomaly detection task. Should I use the Y i have inside the anomaly detection model as a features? Is it an overfitting Risk?

Comment: If you have imbalanced data you can use oversampling or under sampling techniques to deal with it.

Comment: It doesn't  improve my results, for that reason I use anomaly detection

Comment: How large is your dataset?

Comment: 500k x 20. The original labels instead are the following: class a : 480k, class b: 15k, class c: 5k

Comment: To me it is surprising that you would find no improvement from resampling with a data set as large as 500k.

Comment: Also for me was surprising! I tried different under sampling and oversampling but nothing happens. It's something related to the labels and to the poor set of X. For that reasons I was looking for anomaly detection. Do you know any supervised a.d. algorithm for python?

Answer (score 0):

It simply depends on what is the goal of the task:

- If the final goal is still to predict Y after detecting anomalies (i.e. probably using the output of anomaly detection as a feature), then Y cannot be used since it wouldn't be available in a realistic test set.
- If it's just a completely different task in which Y is available as an input, then why not use it.

With 500k instances, A single additional variable with 3 possible values has an extremely low risk of causing overfitting.

Note that since classification didn't work, it's likely that there is little relationship between the features and Y (otherwise there was some mistake in the classification experiment).